# Placing mouse to save position?

Tags: python

I'm trying to place the mouse and click to a save position on the screen.
I can't seem to place the location correctly into the pyautogui.click()

Here the code:

```
import pyautogui

placey = 105
placex = 205
place = placey,',',placex
pyautogui.position(str(place))
pyautogui.click()
```

Anyone here who knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `pyautogui.position()` just gets the mouse position and takes no arguments. Did you mean to use `pyautogui.moveTo()` to move the mouse?

Comment: Also, does `print(str(place))` help you find another problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just click the location without moving first:

```
import pyautogui

place_y = 105
place_x = 205
pyautogui.click(x=place_x, y=place_y)
```

You can move the mouse first, but I mentioned in my comment that you'll need to use `moveTo`, not `position`:

```
import pyautogui

place_y = 105
place_x = 205
pyautogui.moveTo(place_x, place_y)
pyautogui.click()
```

Lastly, this code here isn't doing what you want:

```
placey = 105
placex = 205
place = placey,',',placex
```

The actual value of `place` in this case will be a tuple of 3 values - two `int`s and a `str`:

```
(105, ',', 205)
```

This isn't going to be useful to any of `pyautogui`'s functions. If you want to define a tuple of two integers, just do:

```
place = (place_x, place_y)
# the result:
(105, 205)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the pyautogui documentation `pyautogui.position()` doesnt move the mouse but returns the current position of the mouse.

What you need is `pyautogui.moveTo(placex, placey)`